# oracle sql query select

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle-sqldeveloper, qsqlquery

table tourist

[image]

table stay

[image]

table hotel

[image]

i want to print the names of the tourists who have been to hilton but not to continental so the tourists who have been to hilton and continental both shouldnt be printed

Comment: You are lucky, you got an answer (and a good one at that). Usually you should try something by yourself first and then ask if you get stuck.

Comment: Please don't deface the question, I rolled it back to a previous revision.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `exists` and `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from tourists t
where 
    exists (
        select 1
        from stay s
        inner join hotels h on h.hcode = s.hcode
        where s.tcode = t.tcode and h.name = 'Hilton'
    ) and not exists (
        select 1
        from stay s
        inner join hotels h on h.hcode = s.hcode
        where s.tcode = t.tcode and h.name = 'Continental'  
    )
```